# What is the role of the four-pin header on this USB relay board?

Tags: usb, relay, board

This is a [commonly available](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20relay%20hid&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&&biw=1376&bih=1192&dpr=1.5) relay board with a USB HID-like interface.[image: Two relay board with a USB interface]

I haven't been able to find a datasheet for it on the sites that sell it.  On its right side there's a four pin header.  I'm curious regarding its functionality.  The PCB traces from the header on the bottom of the board lead to through-holes near the IC.  I measured its connectivity and it does not appear to be a mirror of the USB port.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe some debug, or firmware loading interface. That would be easier to say if you gave the chip reference and the pins to which these signals are connected to.

Comment: Good idea!  The markings on the chip are: Atmel 20U — TINY45 — 1913VSR (The last part  I would think is the date / batch code.) I will have to power down the board to measure the pin connectivity. Will try to do so later.

Comment: Many thanks! I was able to answer the question using your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four header pins are connected to pins 1, 7, 6, 5 of the Atmel microcontroller. These can function as [RESET, SCK, MISO, MOSI](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf#page=60) for [serial programming the EEPROM](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf#page=151) by pulling RESET to low.